# .htaccess: specific path allowed all other denied

Tags: .htaccess, controls

folder hierarchy

```
/html => maindomain.com
/html/_subdomain => subdomain.maindomain.com 
/html/_subdomain/anotherdomain => anotherdomain.com and subdomain.maindomain.com/anotherdomain
/html/_subdomain/anotherdomain/admin => anotherdomain.com/admin and subdomain.maindomain.com/anotherdomain/admin
```

I am looking for .htaccess code to deny "anotherdomain.com/admin" and allow "subdomain.maindomain.com/anotherdomain/admin" only just for this folder.
 my code

```
<Directory /html/subdomain/anotherdomain/admin>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from subdomain.maindomain.com/anotherdomain/admin
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `<Directory>` container inside an htaccess file. Inside an htaccess file in the `/html/_subdomain/anotherdomain/admin` directory, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

So if the access isn't from the host **subdomain.maindomain.com**, then the request results in a 403 forbidden.